# WPF Getting selected option of combobox item template

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, dropdown, itemtemplate

I populate my Combobox with textblocks via a datatemplate, since this was the most direct way i could find to populate the dropdown box with a list of variables.
However, now that I am trying to read the value or selected option, I have no idea how to tackle it.
All other topics recommend "SelectedValue.ToString();" or the likes, but this just returns the first line of my XAML..

My Xaml;

```
<ComboBox Name="DropdownDansen" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectedValue="{Binding dans}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding dans}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

my cs:

```
    public List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            people.Add(new Person { id = "0", dans = "Tango", teamlid1 = "Daniel 
", teamlid2 = "Sabrina ", coach = "Hans van Bommel" });
            people.Add(new Person { id = "1", dans = "Wals", teamlid1 = "de Ridder", teamlid2 = "Aninka ", coach = "Hans van Bommel" });
            people.Add(new Person { id = "2", dans = "Foxtrot", teamlid1 = "de Ridder", teamlid2 = "de Ridder", coach = "Hans van Bommel" });
            people.Add(new Person { id = "3", dans = "Quickstep", teamlid1 = "de Ridder", teamlid2 = "de Ridder", coach = "Dansschool van Amersfoort" });

            DropdownDansen.ItemsSource = people;
            displayDans.DataContext = new DisplayText() { deDans = "chachacha" 
    };
            displaylid1.DataContext = new DisplayText() { lid1 = "Kees" };
            displaylid2.DataContext = new DisplayText() { lid2 = "Hariette" };
            displaycoach.DataContext = new DisplayText() { deCoach = "Steve" };
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string dans { get; set; }
            public string teamlid1 { get; set; }
            public string teamlid2 { get; set; }
            public string coach { get; set; }

        }
```

---

Edit:
The answer provided by @mm8 does quite the trick!
However, with the combobox updated, the dropdown menu is filled with the first line of my xaml instead!
[image: screenshot of project]

```
 <ComboBox Name="DropdownDansen" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectedValue="{Binding dans}" SelectedValuePath="dans"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast `SelectedItem` to a `Person`:

```
Person selectedPerson = DropdownDansen.SelectedItem as Person;
if (selectedPerson != null)
{
    string dans = selectedPerson.dans;
}
```

For your binding (`SelectedValue="{Binding dans}"`) to work, `dans` should be a `string` property of the `DataContext` of the `ComboBox` and you should also set the `SelectedValuePath` property to "dans":

```
<ComboBox Name="DropdownDansen" ... SelectedValue="{Binding dans}" SelectedValuePath="dans">
```

Comment: Where exactly do I do the casting? I assume in public MainWindow(), but do I do it before or after adding People?

Comment: @DanieldeRidder: Wherever you you wan to get hold of the selected value, for example in an event handler that gets invoked when you click on a button.

Comment: Awesome, that almost does the trick. I have updated the OP, right now the dropdown is just filled with the first line of my xaml instead. This software hates to work with me haha!

Comment: @DanieldeRidder: Did you remove the ItemTemplate? You may also set the DisplayMemberPath property to "dans" or whatever property you want to display.

Comment: I did remove the ItemTemplate, I thought you wanted to point it it was redundant in my usage. With the DisplayMemberPath property selected, it works like a charm! Thank you very much for your assistance :)